# App dev on Mac Mini 1.1?

Tags: macos

Could the very first generation of the Mac Mini handle app development for the iPhone? My friend said he'd give me his for free to use XCode, but I want to make sure that it could run it before I take it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: For current iOS versions? No. For any iPhone? Yes.

The latest OS X supported on that hardware (officially, don't know about hacks) is 10.6 and the latest Xcode you can get for that is 4.2 ([if you have a paid account, it seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3924758?tstart=0)). [Xcode 4.2 would support iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html), so if that's enough, then it can be used for development for iPhone. But I assume that's not what you're after, since a lot has changed since iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are trying to develop against IOS8. You need OSX 10.9.4(Mavericks) to run XCode 6.1.

[Minimum OS X and xcode requirements for ios 8.1 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712479/minimum-os-x-and-xcode-requirements-for-ios-8-1-development)